# How to group sequences with the same regularity using spark

Tags: java, algorithm, apache-spark, sequence

To simplify the input parameters and code, I've generated an input list (in real live it is a lot of `csv` files with digits inside). All input numbers should be grouped by the single regularity rule. Numbers that can not be described with any regularity rule should be removed from the output result.

### input example:

```
[1010,1020,1050,1030,1022,1880,1940,1900,1920,2010,3100]
```

### output result example:

```
[[1010,1020,1030,1050],[1880,1900,1920,1940]]
```

`[1010,1020,1030,1050]` has increment step `10` and sequence has an exclusion (`1040`). `[1880,1900,1920,1940]` has increment step `20`, sequence without exclusions.

Starting solution with `spark` on `java`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("reduce").setMaster("local[*]");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    List<Integer> inputIntegers = Arrays.asList(1010,1020,1050,1030,1022,1880,1940,1900,1920,2010,3100);
    JavaRDD<Integer> integerRdd = sc.parallelize(inputIntegers);
    System.out.println("Check count of objects: " + integerRdd.count());

    System.out.println(integerRdd.collect());
    JavaRDD<Integer> sorted = integerRdd.sortBy(x -> x, true, 1);
    System.out.println("Check sorted collection:");
    System.out.println(sorted.collect());
   /* TODO
   - enrich data with increment step
   - group by increment step  (increment step should be calculated in run time)
   - filter out single values 
   */
}
```

I think I need to use increment step but I do not know how to manage data from different RDDs (in case of using `spark`), to have a chance save incremental step in current spark RDD

Does anyone have ideas how to resolve my spark issue or how it can be solved with different tools?

### P.S.

Spark (or any equivalent technology) is mandatory because solution must be big data oriented and as result resolved in distributed system.

Comment: so I guess the group should have at least 3 elements, otherwise any pair of elements would satisfy regularity

Comment: @mangusta nicely commented - updated. thanks

Comment: Привіт! Without specifying additional conditions and requirements the algorithmic problem in the background seems to be intractable. In your example input data is already sorted. Also, are you looking for *the same increment* rule only, or other regularity rules are acceptable, e.g sequence `1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11,...`?

Comment: almost sorted (collisions could happen `1010,1020,1050,1030...`), and exclusion rules make issue harder. @yola, Do you know how to group numbers by increment value?

Comment: I'm afraid that i don't know anything about spark. First i would sort the sequence with something like bubble-sort, as you tell that is already sorted. Then i would decide on the biggest possible *step*, that could be deduced from the range of the numbers in the sequence, maybe other considerations as well. And then just routinely check for different step. The first step to consider would be `a[1] - a[0]`.

Comment: Solution in usual way can't be applied for distributed handling. In my case thats mandatory condition

Comment: Are all numbers unique?

Comment: @Nikhil yes. all numbers are unique

Comment: the most trivial solution involves 1.getting all possible increment steps by a single reducer 2. processing <key=increment step, value=your array> by many reducers. but that annihilates the purpose of distributed computing